# Sum up over a colum of word pairs and check for frequency?

Tags: python, pandas

Is it possible to sum up over a column of counts of word combinations with Pandas? Let's assume there is a column with the text given where each cell is a sentence. How can one check if a word pair consisting of 2 words in sentence 1 also appear in the other rows, and if yes the count of such an appearance should be incremented by 1.

It should look like this:

```
|    | text                                     |count|
|---:|:-----------------------------------------|-----|
|  0 | My Name is Anton and I like driving cars | 6   |
|  1 | My Name is Herold and I hate cars        | 6   |
|  2 | This is Lothar, and this is Larox        | 2   |
```

As can been seen from the example above, `My Name` is a word pair that appears in row 0 and row 1, thus add +1 for count. Then `Name is` also appears in row 0 and row 1 etc.

Comment: What exactly defines what a word combination is in this case? are you refering to just words that exist in each line that repeat in others?

Comment: Word combination should consider the order of words. Always two neighbouring words and checking if they exist in each line, whereby the word pair does not necessarily have to be at the same position on each line.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this helps. It doesn't return count as a column like you have shown above - I'm a bit confused by what you're looking for there.

This will return a dictionary of all the pairwise word combinations in a dataframe column and each pair's frequency count, but the count won't be attributable to specific rows.

```
def pairs(lst):
    return zip(lst,lst[1:]+[lst[0]])


def get_pairs(df):
    df["text_list"] = df['column_you_want_to_sum_over'].apply(lambda x: [item for item in 
    str(x).lower().split(" ")])
    pairs_dct = {}
    for i in df.index:
        lst = df.at[i, "text_list"]
        for x in pairs(lst):
            pairs_dct[x] = pairs_dct.get(x,0)+1
    return pairs_dct
```

Output example (based on a different dataframe, just shwon to illustrate the output format visually):

```
{('the', 'world'): 150, ('world', 'you'): 4, ('you', 'could'): 6, ('could', 'buy'): 1, ('buy', 'the'): 3, ('the', 'nfl'): 1}
```

I think you could extend this functionality to then check by row if each pairwise combination in the string is in the dict, and if so, increment count by 1.